# vb.net how to create the login permission

Tags: vb.net, ms-access-2010

```
 Private Sub Edit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Edit.Click
    LoginForm.ShowDialog()
    If Me.DataGridView1.Rows.Count > 0 Then
        If Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows.Count > 0 Then
            Dim intcid1 As Integer = Me.DataGridView1.SelectedRows(0).Cells("ID").Value
            'open connection
            If Not cn3.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
                cn3.Open()
            End If
            'get data into datatable
            Dim da As New OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM stock " & _
                                                 " WHERE cid=" & intcid1, cn3)
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            da.Fill(dt)
            Me.txtbarcode.Text = intcid1
            Me.txtdetail1.Text = dt.Rows(0).Item("CheckerDetail")

            Me.txtbarcode.Tag = intcid1
            'change button save to update
            Me.save.Text = "Update"
            'disable button edit
            'Me.Edit.Enabled = True
            Me.save.Enabled = True
        End If
    End If
    cn3.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub save_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles save.Click
    Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    If Not cn3.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
        'open connection if it is not open yet
        cn3.Open()
    End If
    cmd.Connection = cn3

    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO stock([checkercid],[CheckerName],[ShipQuantity],[Date],[CompanyName],[CheckerDetail]) " &
   "VALUES( '" & getLastNumber().ToString & "','" & Me.txtCN.Text & "', '" & Me.txtQty.Text & "', '" & Date.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss") & "', '" & Me.txtCompanyN.Text & "', '" & Me.txtdetail1.Text & "')"


    'Error message if user not fill yhe textbox
    If txtdetail1.Text.Trim = "" Then
        MessageBox.Show("Please Insert Data", "Error Message")
        Exit Sub
    End If

    cmd.CommandText = "UPDATE stock " & _
            " SET" & _
            " [CheckerDetail]='" & Me.txtdetail1.Text & "'" & _
            " WHERE [cid]=" & DataGridView1("ID", DataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex).Value

    MsgBox("Update Data Successful", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Message")
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Me.btnClear.PerformClick()
    RefreshData1()
    cn3.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: Your users user name and a salted and hashed password and the salt should be stored in a table in your database. User names must be unique. Retrieve the salt form database with the user name. Add the salt to the user entered password and hash that to verify that it matches the password stored in the database. Check the System.Security.Cryptography for hashing classes. No plain text passwords should ever be stored.

Comment: @Mary which mean is i need create a new user table for my access database. and create the login program  for my user login Izzit

Comment: Correct. That would be a start.

Comment: @Mary can you please help me take a look.above code is i new create for my user login part i have still problem on cancel part if user press cancel button on the system the data still can update.

Comment: On what form is the cancel button? Where is your code for the event handler of the cancel button?

Comment: @Mary seen i no need create the cancel button. buti still  face the issue is if user press the (X) on my login form and fail login the user still can update by user.

Comment: Have you reviewed my answer? What exactly happens when user clicks the X? Is the login form the start up form?

Comment: @mary yes i have reviewed your answer.my program flow chat is when user would like to (edit data on form 1) > user need(login first)>if login success > user can edit the data >if user login fail (3time) it will return to form1 user will fail to edit data. the (X) mean is meaning of close form it is a icon. in current my program process is when user would like to (edit data on form 1) > user need (login first)>if login success > user can edit the data >if user login fail (3time) it will return close from 1 if user press the window form( (X) it is a icon) user can edit the data without password.

Comment: @mary i have use LoginForm.ShowDialog() on my edit button. cause i want user when click the edit button it can edit data as privacy cause user need login first still can edit the data.Private Sub Edit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Edit.Click

        LoginForm.ShowDialog()

Comment: `If Not cn3.State = ConnectionState.Open Then` You should never have to ask this question if you keep your database objects local.

Comment: Do not open connections when you are using a DataAdapter. The adapter will open and close the connection for you. However, if it finds and open connection it leaves it open.

Comment: Always use Parameters. Do not concatenate strings in Sql statements. See https://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 0):

I moved things around trying to keep the User Interface code in the Form and the Data Access code in your class. You had Retries in 2 different places. You only need it in one. boolresetPassword is never used in your code. Since you are hard coding the password don't set a bunch of properties of the class in the form. Just put your connection string in the constructor of the connection in the class. The validated data for the LogIn function is passed to the function.

You don't need all those properties in your class. Just add your connection string. You can pass your Select statement and the connection directly to the constructor of the command. Don't use .AddWithValue. See http://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/
and
https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/
and another one:
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/195937/addwithvalue-performance-and-plan-cache-implications

I changed the Select to retrieve Count which is all you need to know.

As far as the Cancel button ask a new question with the code for the cancel button.

```
Public Class LoginForm
    Private Retrys As Integer 'Integers automatically initialize to zero

    Private Sub Ok_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Ok.Click
        If Retrys = 2 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry, you have exceeded the maximum number of attempts to login")
            Close()
        End If

        Dim AppLogin As New ApplicatioLogin
        'Do your validation here; not in the Data Access code.
        If Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(un.Text) AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pw.Text) Then
            If AppLogin.Login(un.Text, pw.Text) Then
                SensitiveDataForm.Load()
                Close()
            Else
                Retrys += 1
                MessageBox.Show("Login Failed")
            End If
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Please fill in both username and password")
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
Public Class ApplicatioLogin
        Public Function Login(UserName As String, UserPassword As String) As Boolean
            Dim recordCount As Integer
            Using cn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection("Your connection string")
                Using cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand("SELECT Count(*) FROM Users 
                    WHERE UserName = @UserName AND UserPassword = @UserPassword", cn)
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = UserName
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserPassword", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = UserPassword
                    cn.Open()
                    recordCount = CInt(cmd.ExecuteScalar)
                End Using
            End Using
            If recordCount = 1 Then
                Return True
            Else
                Return False
            End If
        End Function
End Class
```

Comment: on SensitiveDataForm have error did i create the dim for SensitiveDataForm.code

Comment: is i need add some code on my edit button force my edit button need fill the correct username and password still can edit.

Comment: What is on the form that calls the LoginForm? Is the data visible here but not editable?

Comment: How is the data displayed? In a DataGridView?

Comment: form 1 will call my login form. Is the data visible here but not editable (it can edit, but i would crate the secure page to let the user login first b4 edit). How is the data displayed? In a DataGridView? (the data grid view display the user insert data)